# creating posts using rake routes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

tutorial indicates that if i run `rake routes` this should be expected

```
$ rake routes
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
     root        /                         welcome#index
```

but when i issue the command, this only shows up

```
welcome_index GET /welcome/index(.:format) welcome#index
         root     /                        welcome#index
```

what might be the reason behind this?

link - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: add comment `#` like this : `# get "welcome/index"` and  `# root to: "welcome#index"`, and then put `resources :posts`

Comment: thank you for answering this newbie question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following to the `routes.rb`

```
resources :posts
```